# How to solve "sudo: /etc/sudoers.d is world writable"

Tags: sudo

How can I fix the following error with `sudo`?

```
/etc$ sudo
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d is world writable
usage: sudo [-D level] -h | -K | -k | -V
usage: sudo -v [-AknS] [-D level] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user
            name|#uid]
usage: sudo -l[l] [-AknS] [-D level] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-U user
            name] [-u user name|#uid] [-g groupname|#gid] [command]
usage: sudo [-AbEHknPS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C fd] [-D level] [-g
            groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user name|#uid] [-g groupname|#gid]
            [VAR=value] [-i|-s] [<command>]
usage: sudo -e [-AknS] [-r role] [-t type] [-C fd] [-D level] [-g
            groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user name|#uid] file ...
```

Comment: looks like changing permissions on `/etc` is a bad thing http://serverfault.com/questions/364677/why-is-chmod-r-777-destructive http://serverfault.com/questions/221447/how-to-repair-restore-ubuntu-10-04-after-sudo-chmod-777

Comment: try `pkexec chmod 555 /etc/sudoers`

Comment: If "pkexec chmod 555 /etc/sudoers.d" does not work for you due to pkexec having a permission promblem, get the PID of the shell you are running pkexec in suing "echo $$" then log in another window and do a " pkttyagent --process XXX" with the XXX replaced with the PID of the other shell. Once that is running, retry the pkexec in other shell

Comment: Thank you, @CullenFluffyJennings. That worked for me. Keep safe...

Answer (score 48):

Run `pkexec chmod 0755 /etc/sudoers.d`

`pkexec` will use a different method of using root permissions, bypassing the issue.
And the `chmod` will fix the permissions.

Comment: did not help :(

Comment: @demure , which password i have to use?

Comment: I have tried pkexec chmod 0755 /etc

Comment: `Error executing command as another user: Not authorized` if I could switch to the root user I wouldn't need to do this in the first place...

Comment: This will not work if you are not running a graphical environment

Answer (score 40):

Run this 2 commands with (555) permissions:

```
pkexec chmod 555 /etc/sudoers
pkexec chmod 555 /etc/sudoers.d/README
```

Comment: Worked for me. Fantastic!

Comment: worked for me great

Comment: its worked for me :)

Comment: works great on LTS 16.04

Comment: This will not work if you are not running a graphical environment

Comment: Worked for me Thank you, @KamalJain.

Comment: Linux mint: worked like a charm!

Answer (score 12):

Did you try going into recovery mode and switching the permissions back to 775 for sudoers? I tried it and it worked.

1) Get into Ubuntu Recovery

2) Do `mount -rw -o remount /`

3) Then `chmod 775 -R /etc/sudoers` and `chmod 775 -R /etc/sudoers.d/`.

This time it should work.

4) Then do a sudo apt-get install of any package to test before you leave recovery mode.
Late reply but I encountered the issue recently and tried this. It worked fine atleast for the world writable issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "Get into Ubuntu Recovery"? Once I'm at the recovery menu do I select `root`? That gets me to a root shell that is in recovery but this doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I got `sudo` to work by using live USB, mounting in `/mnt`, and `chroot /mnt`

Comment: thanks Gdcrocx. its work

Comment: after I execute the commands you wrote in recovery mode and restart, they are no more valid.