# How to fix sudo after “chmod -R 777 /var”?

Tags: chmod

I executed `chmod 777  /var` and now Ubuntu won't start, can anyone tell me what I did wrong? And if there is a way of going back?

Comment: I can't understand: in the title you have used `-R`, in the question body you haven't. Which one is the right one? (I suspect `-R` is what you have typed.)

Answer (score 2):

This is a security issue: inside /var are files that never are accepted when set to executable for "the whole world" (the 3rd 7 in your command).

If you did -not- use `-R` with that command this should fix it:

```
sudo chmod 755 /var
```

For future reference please read this:

- [Why shouldn't /var/www have chmod 777](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20105/why-should-var-www-not-have-chmod-777)

Comment: I tried "sudo chmod 755 /var" But it didn't work and got this message "sudo: /etc/sudoers.d is world writable"

Comment: @rayan: http://askubuntu.com/questions/304212/how-to-solve-sudo-etc-sudoers-d-is-world-writable