# sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers.d/README: No such file or directory

Tags: permissions, sudo, chmod

Whenever i use `sudo` command i get this message:

```
sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers.d/README: No such file or directory
```

i ran into this trouble when i was strugling with chmod using which i changed the permissions on `/etc/sudoers`, `/etc/sudoers.d` and also `/etc/sudoers.d/README`

I solved the issue with `/etc/sudoers` from [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304212/how-to-solve-sudo-etc-sudoers-d-is-world-writable).

Nut now when I look at the permissions of the file `/etc/sudoers.d/README`, it says 'the permissions of README could not be determined'

This happens when i use ls

```
ls -l /etc/sudoers.d/
ls: cannot access /etc/sudoers.d/README: Permission denied
total 0
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? README
```

Comment: provide results of `ls -l /etc/sudoers.d/` please

Comment: ls -l /etc/sudoers.d/
ls: cannot access /etc/sudoers.d/README: Permission denied
total 0
-????????? ? ? ? ?            ? README

Comment: Actually, provides the results of **THIS** command `ls -ld /etc/sudoers.d`

Comment: @user2459314 the dir above the file is wrong (and to be exact: that dir is NOT set as executable) (0xsheepdog's command will be correct; my answer (the 2nd part) will restore it)

Answer (score 9):

This is what it should be:

```
ls -l /etc/sudoers.d/
total 4
-r--r----- 1 root root 958 feb 10 20:20 README
```

so to restore permissions do a:

```
sudo chown root:root /etc/sudoers.d/README
sudo chmod 440 /etc/sudoers.d/README
```

---

From comments: the level above seems wrong so do this 1st:

```
ls -ltr /etc | grep sudoers.d
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root       4096 mrt 20 08:32 sudoers.d
```

so to restore permissions do a:

```
sudo chown root:root /etc/sudoers.d
sudo chmod 755 /etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: My CentOS65 box shows `/etc/sudoers.d` as 750, but my 14.04 box reflects your answer, 755. The difference is to support/protect Debians addition of the `#includedir /etc/sudoers.d` to its baseline `/etc/sudoers` file. **shrug**

Comment: Funny :D I have no centos here (at work I do). Never knew those are different.

Comment: @0xSheepdog The `750` permissions on CentOs `/etc/sudoers.d` means that users who are not the owner of, nor in the same group as, `/etc/sudoers.d` cannot see (lookup, stat, read) within `/etc/sudoers.d`