# Apache "Restart" not working

Tags: server, apache2, mysql, php, lamp

I install apache2 package and i run this command line from terminal and it getting me error like this

```
user@user:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart 
sudo: /etc/sudoers.d is world writable
/etc/init.d/apache2: 64: .: Can't open /etc/apache2/envvars
/etc/init.d/apache2: 76: .: Can't open /etc/apache2/envvars
ERROR: APACHE_PID_FILE needs to be defined in /etc/apache2/envvars
```

can anyone help me for this.

Comment: It seems the file `/etc/apache2/envvars` is missing which is part of the `apache2` package. Did you get any error messages during install or did you manually remove/move something? Btw. you should run `chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers`.

Comment: possible duplicate http://askubuntu.com/questions/304212/how-to-solve-sudo-etc-sudoers-d-is-world-writable

Answer (score 0):

Did you accidentally changed permissions and/or ownership on the files envvars and sudoers.d? Because apache is not able to open the envvars file. Also the sudoers.d directory seems to have different permissions than when it was installed. Use the commands below to change permissions and ownership of the file and directory.

```
sudo chmod 755 /etc/sudoers.d
```

User and group should be root - change like this:

```
sudo chown root: /etc/sudoers.d
```

And for the envvars files

```
sudo chmod 644 /etc/apache2/envvars

sudo chown root: /etc/apache2/envvars
```