# Error with sudo : /etc/sudoers is world writable , no valid sudoers sources found

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo

```
sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I was installing a font by using this command

```
sudo gnome-font-viewer /home/user-15/Downloads/aclonica/Aclonica.ttf
```

[image]

I used this before and it worked fine but now it is not working, I'm not able to install any font.

Comment: I found a similar post here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/304212/how-to-solve-sudo-etc-sudoers-d-is-world-writable

Comment: That answer is'nt working at my side

Comment: @TarunNarula Please [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/886769/edit) your question and add what you tried and what didn't work.

Comment: @MadMike I edited my question

Comment: @TarunNarula Please add what you tried from this question [How to solve "sudo: /etc/sudoers.d is world writable"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/304212/how-to-solve-sudo-etc-sudoers-d-is-world-writable) and what didn't work.

Comment: I use that cmd Run pkexec chmod 0755 /etc/sudoers.d

Comment: pkexec chmod 555 /etc/sudoers
pkexec chmod 555 /etc/sudoers.d/README

Comment: @TarunNarula It would be easier to follow what you have tried if you [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/886769/edit) and update your question with that information, instead of using comments.

Answer (score 0):

1. Boot up an Ubuntu live distro (via USB or CD).
2. Mount your root file system.  (let's say your root file system was mounted to `/mnt`)
3. Execute `sudo chmod o-w /mnt/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: chmod: changing permissions of '/etc/sudoers': Operation not permitted

Comment: From the Ubuntu live CD you need to be root.  Added `sudo` to my answer.