# sudo su is denied in Ubuntui 18.04

Tags: sudo

```
irbi@kirbi-Aspire-ES1-433:~$ sudo su
sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
kirbi@kirbi-Aspire-ES1-433:~$
```

How to fix this?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/304212/how-to-solve-sudo-etc-sudoers-d-is-world-writable https://askubuntu.com/questions/189818/how-to-repair-sudo-etc-sudoers-is-mode-0640-should-be-0440 https://askubuntu.com/questions/886769/error-with-sudo-etc-sudoers-is-world-writable-no-valid-sudoers-sources-foun

Comment: Or more generic:  https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b&ei=eGd6W6DNO5LewQLV_4a4BA&q=site%3Aaskubuntu.com+sudo%3A+%2Fetc%2Fsudoers+is+world+writable&oq=site%3Aaskubuntu.com+sudo%3A+%2Fetc%2Fsudoers+is+world+writable&gs_l=psy-ab.3...8196.12165.0.12522.19.19.0.0.0.0.212.1486.13j4j1.18.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..3.2.191...0i7i30k1j0i13k1j0i8i7i30k1j0i13i30k1j0i8i13i30k1.0.gRGteKr9dIg

Comment: pkexec chmod 555 /etc/sudoers

pkexec chmod 555 /etc/sudoers.d/README

above commands worked ! issue is fixed