# Weird error cannot figure out how to solve

Tags: server

I can't remember what command I ran that did this but I can't seem to do anything because of this error. Is there way to reverse it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFDYo.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve "sudo: /etc/sudoers.d is world writable"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304212/how-to-solve-sudo-etc-sudoers-d-is-world-writable)

Comment: @Terrance no it just says not authorized

Comment: There are other answers there to try to resolve your issue with, but if you cannot resolve them that way you are probably looking at a reinstall of your OS.

Comment: did you happen to notice that both your title and the text of your question give absolutely zero information about what the problem is? Please make your titles and questions descriptive, and rely on images/etc as little as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I can understand from the image you have attached is that:

1. Your sudoers file's permissions are not correct.

To fix that you can try the following:

```
su root                            # login to root, if you are not already logged in as root
chmod 644 /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so # this make it only writable by the owner
chown -R root /usr/lib/sudo        # to set the owner as root
```

In case if you're having trouble with `su root` try
`pkexec su`

I'm a new contributor, so I'm sorry if my answers are not good enough.

Comment: I just ended up reinstalling the server