# I can't run terminal as root

Tags: command-line, sudo, root

When I run `sudo su` or any other command with sudo this is the output

```
sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is world writable sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is world writable sudo: /etc/sudoers is world writable sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting sudo: error initializing audit plugin sudoers_audit
```

When I try to fix using `policykit`,it gives me this output:

```
Error checking for authorization org.freedesktop.policykit.exec: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NoReply: Message recipient disconnected from message bus without replying
```

When I try `systemctl status policykit`, I get this:

[image: log]

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to solve "sudo: /etc/sudoers.d is world writable"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/304212/how-to-solve-sudo-etc-sudoers-d-is-world-writable)??

Comment: More or less yes, but i can't even run pkexec chmod 0755 /etc/sudoers.d the output i have already mentioned

Comment: No and is here any other way how to run terminal as root without sudo command

Comment: Or i tried su - but i didn't set any password for that so i tried su passwd root and this is the output erko@Carrot

:~$ su passwd root

su: user passwd does not exist or the user entry does not contain

all the required fields

erko@Carrot:~$

Comment: Have you tried using the *recovery* mode as suggested by one of the answers to the *duplicate*?   If none work, boot *live* media & make the change from there is what I'd likely do, but you've provided no Ubuntu product/release details so we can only be *generic* in advice.

Comment: I would like to know if i can run terminal as root somehow without using sudo su

Comment: The easiest way on a Ubuntu system is just use the appropriate *recovery* option; which is just a menu driven way of telling the system to boot into specific modes (*which is what you'd use if not using Ubuntu*). As the *root* user is *disabled* by default on Ubuntu systems (using `sudo` closing one security weakness) direct logins cannot be used; but if *enabled* you can login as *root* just like any other system.  Others methods (`pkexec` etc) can depend on product/release details you've not provided.

Comment: Amd how can i do that. And will I still have my files?

Comment: I don't understand what I mentioned relates in any way to your files (*I was talking about alternate booting alternatives*) ... but again you've not said what Ubuntu product, nor what release of that *unstated* product thus I'm limited (*as per prior comments*) to providing *generic* advice.  (*eg. I'm a Desktop user, thus I expect I can re-install and not lose any of my files, my setups etc. but I'm not even talking about re-install here, but alternate boot methods of your existing system*)

Comment: I tried to get to grub menu but nothing happened i switch on the computer and pressed shift and hold shift and it normally start the ubuntu

Comment: Is it right or left shift?

Comment: I dont know how to get to grub menu. I have asus mother board